# passing a data-attribute conditional statement into a loop crashes browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working on code where if you are clicking on something and the data attribute of the clicked link and a section don't match, hide it. I'm attempting to do this by looping through the title elements that don't match the data-attribute of the clicked link.

Below is the code with comments of my intention:

```
var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".authors-titles")
$(".filter-item").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get data attribute of clicked link
  var targetLetter = $(this).attr("data-letter");

  // I try to loop through only the titles with data attributes that dont match the clicked link
  // I'm not sure about implementation but basically for titles who aattributes are not equal to the one gotten through the link
  for (var i = 0; i < titles.dataset != targetLetter; i++) {
    // hide the elements that get returned in this loop, in this case the non matched data attributes
    $(".authors-titles").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

The markup sample:

```
<ul id="filter">
        <li><a data-letter="a" href="#" class="filter-item">a</a></li>
        <li><a data-letter="b" href="#" class="filter-item">b</a></li>
        <li><a data-letter="c" href="#" class="filter-item">c</a></li>
      </ul>

<section data-title="a" class="authors-titles">
      <span class="alphabet">#</span>
      <div class="filter-item-grid">
        <div class="filter-item">
          <h3 class="filter-title">1984</h3>
          <p>By: <a href="#">George Orwell</a> </p>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-item">
          <h3 class="filter-title">2001: A Space Oddyseey</h3>
          <p>By: <a href="#">Author C. Clark</a> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

So basically all I'm really trying to do is see if data-letter and data-title don't match, then hide it.

My main question is this code triggers an infinity loop and completely crashes my browser but I don't understand why. I tried adding `length` to this line:

```
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length.dataset != targetLetter; i++) {
```

But I get the same result.

Comment: Do you have your code wrapped in a $(function(){ // your code here }); or possibly an IIFE

Comment: I do yes, I don't think that's the problem as I can see the function being called

Comment: If you wanted to hide sections that don't match a given attribute, you could just do `$('.authors-title[data-title!="' + yourAttribute + '"]').hide()`. No need to loop manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) is an object of the custom data-attributes.

```js
$(".filter-item").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var letter = this.dataset.letter;
  // loop through the sections
  $(".authors-titles").each(function () {
    // show section only if title is equal to letter
    $(this).toggle(this.dataset.title === letter);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filter">
        <li><a data-letter="a" href="#" class="filter-item">a</a></li>
        <li><a data-letter="b" href="#" class="filter-item">b</a></li>
        <li><a data-letter="c" href="#" class="filter-item">c</a></li>
      </ul>

<section data-title="a" class="authors-titles">
a</section>

<section data-title="b" class="authors-titles">
b</section>

<section data-title="c" class="authors-titles">
c</section>
```

Also, no need to use document.querySelector* if you are using jQuery.